# Snowflake - CREATE table with a date variable in its name

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I would like to create a table in snowflake, appending the date to the end of its name. What is the best way to do that?

- original table = "DB"."SCHEMA"."CLONEME"
- desired new table = "DB"."SCHEMA"."CLONEME_20200812BKP"

Tried setting the date variables, but it didn't work.

First attempt:

```
set var1= (SELECT TO_CHAR(DATE_TRUNC('DAY',CONVERT_TIMEZONE('UTC', CURRENT_DATE())),'YYYYMMDD'));
set var2 = concat('DB.SCHEMA.CLONEME_',$var1);
create table $var2 clone DB.SCHEMA.CLONEME;
-- and got the following error:
-- SQL compilation error: syntax error line 1 at position 13 unexpected '$var2'.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend using the IDENTIFIER function:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/identifier-literal.html

Example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE  TABLE CLONEME(
    src_string VARCHAR(20));

INSERT INTO CLONEME 
VALUES('JKNHJYGHTFGRTYGHJ'), ('ABC123'), (null), ('0123456789');

set var1= (SELECT TO_CHAR(DATE_TRUNC('DAY',CONVERT_TIMEZONE('UTC', CURRENT_DATE())),'YYYYMMDD'));
set var2 = concat('CLONEME_',$var1);

SELECT getvariable('VAR1'), getvariable('VAR2');
--20200812  CLONEME_20200812

create table identifier($var2) clone CLONEME;
--Table CLONEME_20200812 successfully created
```